# Number formatting in Java

Tags: java

I need the following number format in java:

```
long a=5000;
```

Expected output is : 
`50,00`

if

```
long a = 25624;
```

Expected output is : `256,24`

```
long a = 614324;
```

Expected output is

```
6143,24
```

How can I get this in java?

Comment: What kind for format is this? Why is the comma after the *second* digit?

Comment: Is it like only single comma after second digit and rest all chars remain as it is ?

Comment: @Tichodroma no mate, it's that the last two digits are hundredths (cents or whatever)

Comment: This question is fairly easy and can be solved in hundreds of ways, without any specific knowledge. Please first try things out before posting such questions.

Comment: @Tichodroma, in many parts of Europe a decimal comma is used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String.format("%d,%02d",a/100, a%100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatter class in java is used to create formatted output. To do so, the format() method is used. Syntax of format() method is as shown below:

```
Formatter format(String fmtString, Object ... args)
```

For the number format in your program the following can be done:

```
Formatter f = new Formatter();
f.format("%d,%2d",a/100,a%100);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",(double)a / 100);
```

Comment: good for 99% of the cases. However, for very long longs you might have the last digit rounded off to something else due to a loss of precision during the conversion to a double.

Comment: Does not work anyway as it is not usinga "," but a "." as decimal point.

Comment: uses dot or comma based on current (default) Locale. Try this: long a = 5000; Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY); System.out.printf("%.2f",(double)a / 100); THIS WILL OUTPUT A COMMA...